# Deactivate a Google Play app that is currently in review seems impossible?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

My app is in review, received a note stating non-compliant SDK version and I need to deactivate the "wrong" release and upload a new version without the SDK. I haven't found any option to remove it. Is it possible to deactivate releases that are in review? Can you confirm if it's enough to upload new release or am I missing something?